# Unity2D - Method to create a fixed size dynamic terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity/C# and building a simple game in order to learn it; essentially it involves flying over a terrain and shooting at things.

The question is - How can I create a non-flat, fixed size (ie, not endless) 2D terrain that I can randomise/generate once at the start of a scene.

Here's what I've thought/tried so far:

I started off by creating a massive, flat expanse using a game object with a Sprite Renderer and a Box Collider 2D. I'm using particles for rocket trails and explosions and set them to collide with a plane which worked well. This works, but the terrain is just flat and boring.

Next, I drew some rudimentary mountains in photoshop, added them as sprites with polygon collider 2D components and dragged them onto the scene (with an idea to randomise their locations later). This is quick and works well but doesn't play nice with the particles because of the 2D/3D mix, and I imagine would lead to all levels looking the same unless I can draw a LOT of different terrain sprites. Is this a normal approach? Is it possible to add more planes to the objects to allow particles to collide?

Another thought was - could I create a polygon collider 2D / or edge collider 2D and basically fill the area with a texture? No luck on that one, it seems like it could work but I couldn't get a texture to appear and fit the shape. A shame, especially as I could then generate or randomise the position of the points later.

Finally, I wondered whether I should just use 3D shapes. I can texture them and it works great with the particles, but doesn't interact right now with all my other 2D assets, I'd have to add 3D colliders to them and that doesn't seem right, since Unity specifically provides a 2D toolset and I am trying to make a 2D game.

All of my solutions have pros and cons - maybe there's something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create meshes procedurally in unity in scripts. They can be either 2d or 3d depending on how you set the vertices. Colliders are independent of the rendered mesh. I dont have an indepth tutorial for this but i think this video will hint you in the right direction and give you keywords to google or read about in the unity documentation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPX8dw283X4

Comment: I did see that video (a few times) and am none the wiser how to actually create such a thing. At the moment I am working with a block landscape built up of 2D sprites with colliders, its a bit retro but seems to run smoothly enough (as long as I don't try to add rigidbodies to them all!)